# sqlite3 optimization vs reliability

Tags: c, database, optimization, sqlite

I'm in a project where the reliability and robustness of the data is very important. So I'm implementing a system of redundancy on the data store.

I use sqlite3 in c language. To implement the redundancy I have thought to store the same data in three different databases. Then to know if one database is corrupt I have only to compare it.
But my problem, is that this storage in three different databases is very slow, due to I have to open the three databases, do three INSERT at each database and  close the three databases.

I have looked for information about how optimize sqlite3, and I have found for example the pragma statements. I have tested the program with the following instruction in each database:

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF", NULL, NULL, &errMsg);
```

Then the data storage is much faster but I think that with this instruction I'm losing all the reliability that I was finding.

Hence, I would like to know which mechanism I can implement to optimize sqlite3 storage, but not lose the reliability of data.

Comment: Is this a client application? What kinds of corruption risks do you see and want to avoid? Databases are extremely good at staying uncorrupted. You basically only have to deal with bugs in your code and with random disk errors.

Comment: This is an application to an embedded computer (PortuxG20) that has different sensors. I want to store the data sensors acquisition in databases. I don't know which kinds of corruption risks have these databases, but I must do this implementation of redundancy. You offer me use only one database? If I use three, can I improve the performance?